# In TCP, How many data is buffered if the connection is not accepted by the server?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I write a simple server application. In that application, I created a server socket and put it into the listen state with listen call.
After that, I did not write any code to accept the incoming connection request. I simply waited for the termination with pause call.

I want to figure out practically that how many bytes are buffered in the server side if the connection is not accepted. Then I want to validate the number with the theory of the TCP.

To do that,
First, I started my server application.
Then I used "dd" and "netcat" to send the data from client to server. Here is the command:

```
$> dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=100000 | nc 127.0.0.1 45001
```

Then I opened wireshark and wait for the zero-window message.
[image: Wirehark output]

From the last properly acknowledged tcp frame. the client side can successfully send 64559 byte data to the server.

Then I execute the above dd-netcat command to create another client and send data again.
In this case, I got the following wireshark output:
[image: Second wireshark output]

From the last successfully acknowledged tcp frame, I understand that the client application can successfully sent 72677 bytes to the server.

So, it seems that the size of the related buffer can change in runtime. Or, I misinterpret the output of the wireshark.

How can I understand the size of the related receive buffer? What is the correct name to refer that receive buffer in terminology? How can I show the default size of the related receive buffer?

Note that the port number of the tcp server is "45001".

Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for the size of the socket receive buffer at the server. If not defaulted, it is inherited from the setting at the listening socket.

Comment: Is the socket receive buffer allocated when threeway-handshake is complete regardless of the connection request is accepted or not? @user207421

Comment: In practice I think that must be so, but it isn't mandated by the RFCs.

Comment: When I checked when the zero window message appears, I noticed that the number of acknowledged bytes is different in each example. Is the default size of the socket receive buffer change from time to time?